# What is the proper way to install NPM and NodeJS?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, ubuntu, npm

What is the proper way to install NPM and NodeJS ?

**Method 1 .**: `sudo apt-get install npm`

```
sudo apt-get install npm

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

======================================================================
**Method 2.** `curl -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sh`

```
curl -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sh  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    132      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   132
100  6239  100  6239    0     0   1976      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  6986
tar=/bin/tar
version:
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
install npm@latest
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.4.1.tgz
unbuild npm@2.5.0
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/tmp/npm.14799/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.4.1
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/bin/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npm.14799/package/npm-debug.log

> npm@2.4.1 prepublish /tmp/npm.14799/package
> node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j8 doc

make: Nothing to be done for `doc'.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/tmp/npm.14799/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.4.1
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/bin/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/bin/npm' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npm.14799/package/npm-debug.log
It failed
```

In Both cases i was unable to get install npm please guide me thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NVM should be used.

First run

`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.1/install.sh | bash`

After

```
nvm install 0.12
```

This will provide you with working node. If you want to know more about other advantages of nvm - read more at https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score -1):

Since i cant comment yet..

you need to run method 2 as `root` thats why your getting `EACCES` errors

`sudo curl -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`

Comment: I had tried with sudo as well 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/tmp/npm.17810/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.4.1
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/bin/npm'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/bin/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any suppor.....

Comment: Thanks NooBskie let me try

Comment: maybe try running as root from `su -` then running the command

Comment: How does the Nodejs get installed , installing npm. The answer is not related to the question